# Однородные определения и обособляемый оборот

Tags: однородные-члены, определения

Возник вопрос по следующему предложению: Не используйте разные, порой сомнительные(,) источники для получения информации.
Нужна ли запятая перед словом "источники"? 
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Я понимаю, если бы вы хотели поставить запятую перед "источниками", но не после же!

Comment: Ой, прошу прощения! Сейчас откорректирую вопрос.

Comment: Из предложения следует исключить слова «разные, порой». Оставить только «сомнительные» — и вопрос с запятой решится сам собой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласна со Славой, лучше поправить предложение, убрав  слова «разные, порой», но если говорить о предложенном предложении, то запятая не нужна. Я вижу здесь неоднородные определения с пояснительными отношениями, такие, как в справочнике Лопатина:

> § 41. Неоднородные определения разделяются запятой только в том
>   случае, если второе из них поясняет первое, раскрывая его содержание
>   (возможна вставка слов то есть, а именно): Он... осторожно ступал по
>   блестящей проволоке с новым, свежим чувством восторга (Гран.) — здесь
>   новый значит «свежий»; без запятой, т. е. при снятии пояснительных
>   отношений, окажется иной смысл: было «свежее чувство восторга» и
>   появилось новое (новое свежее чувство, но: новое, свежее чувство); —
>   Приюти сиротку, — вступил третий, новый голос (М. Г.) — определение
>   новый поясняет определение третий; Нет у природы более талантливых и
>   менее талантливых произведений. Делить на те и другие их можно только
>   с нашей, человеческой точки зрения (Сол.). Ср.: В дачном поселке
>   появились новые кирпичные дома (к имевшимся кирпичным домам
>   прибавились еще другие). — В дачном поселке появились новые, кирпичные
>   дома (до этого кирпичных домов не было).

https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114

В этом случае между определениями ставится запятая, но сами определения не выделяются, второй запятой нет:

*Не используйте разные, порой сомнительные источники для получения информации.*

Answer (score 0):

Всё дело в слове ***разные***, оно не подходит сюда по смыслу. Поэтому его надо заменить, например:

*Не используйте малоизвестные, **порой сомнительные,** источники для получения информации.*

Только **после редактирования**  можно говорит о правильной постановке знаков.

В этом предложении **обособление возможно**, так как однородные отношения здесь не просматриваются. Малоизвестный источник не обязательно сомнительный, поэтому оборот может иметь  значение **дополнительного уточнения или пояснения.**

По Розенталю, "вопрос об отделении с одной стороны или выделении с двух сторон пояснительного определения решается **в условиях контекста**".

*В утренней прохладе разлит горький запах полыни, смешанный с нежным, **похожим на миндаль,** ароматом повилики* (Купр.).

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108

*Четвёртая, **по-видимому последняя**, часть романа завершится эпилогом.*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119